# extjs 4 textarea auto complete/suggestion

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, extjs4, extjs4.2, autosuggest

One of the new requirement we have is to have a formula editor where user can enter some sort of formula (excel type) such as

```
IF($Field1 < 1000, 'Message 1') AND
IF($Field2 > 10000,'Message 2')
```

so the idea here is that we should do auto suggestion (contextual) for "Function(IF)" , "Field(Field1 and Field2)","Condition (AND)" , "Operator (>)"  as user types in the textarea (so it not going to be Multiline).

so basically we are trying to mimic the same functionality what jira has where it does auto suggest for resolution, fixVersion etc like shown below 
so far i ave tried [this Sencha Forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135922-How-to-add-auto-complete-to-textarea.) but with that i get behavior like multi select combo box which we dont want. 
 so my problems are 
1. Contextual Auto complete for textarea 
2. Syntax parsing for the formula to get the context. 
[image: Jira's Contextual autosuggestion] 
 and this [image]

i really need help here, as google is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

here what i did to fix my auto suggest issue

```
 var textField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        width: 200,
        height:200
    });   


    textField.on('keypress', function(f){
      // debugger;
        var val = f.getValue();

        if(val){
            var query = val;
            console.log(query);
            store.clearFilter();

            store.filter('Name', query);

            dataview.show();

        } else {
            dataview.hide()
        }


    }, this, {
        buffer: 200
    });



    var dataview = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
        height: 200,
        width: 50,
        store: store,
        itemTpl: '{Name}',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        hidden: true,
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(view, rec){
                var val = textField.getValue();

                val = val.replace(nameRegex, '@' + rec.get('Name'));

                textField.setValue(val);

                dataview.hide();

                textField.focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great answer, I've created a fiddle for this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/28oi

Answer (score 0):

Create a combobox with all possible values you want to suggest User and on keypress event of textarea populate combo with filtered record as per typed characters.
Example - I type a fieldName and then a space, for this case show all operators by filter combo.

Comment: combo box multi text - can you be more clear on this.

Comment: what i meant to was , combo box does not allow you to change the height,  what i want is a textarea where user can see multiple line at once just like other HTML editor..